Fantasy novel about an orphaned boy who gives a wizard a mango and becomes his apprentice
I do not remember exactly when I read this book, it was likely close to 19 or so years ago, but here are the details that I remember.

The book starts with an orphaned boy, I think in India or some similar setting, who is bringing food back for his sister
The boy meets a beggar who he gives a mango to, the beggar reveals himself to be a wizard
I believe from this point the wizard promises to teach the boy magic in return for his kindness
at some point the wizard is turned into a weasel and they need to find a magic conch to change the wizard back.

These are all of the details that I can find and the only story critical objects are the mango and the conch shell.

Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy SE! Please consider registering your account, which gives you access to more site features. As a registered user, you will be able to vote, and you won’t lose access to your post if you switch devices or browsers, or when your browser cookies are cleared. Registering is easy and allows you to participate fully in our community. For more info, see Why should I register my account?
